# Increment a column value based on a combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
OwnerID    GroupID    AssignmentID   ... <few more columns>  [Need this column]
1           10         100                                    1
1           10         100                                    1
1           10         200                                    2
1           20         100                                    1
1           20         200                                    2
1           20         300                                    3
2           30         200                                    1
2           30         200                                    1
2           40         300                                    2
```

I would like to populate a column based on the values in `OwnerID`, `GroupID` and `AssignmentID` fields. If the values in these fields are the same across rows, then I want the number `1` repeated in the new column. But if the same owner has assigned a different assignment to the same group, then the value in the new column should increment.

For example - `OwnerID` `1` assigned 2 assignments (2 with the same `AssignmentID` 100 and the other with `AssignmentID` 200). The `AssignmentID` 100 gets value `1` in both cases because the values for `OwnerID`, `GroupID` and `AssignmentID` are the same, but gets the value 2 when the `AssignmentID` is 200.

Similarly, when `OwnerID` 100 assigned `AssignmentID` 100, 200 and 300, the group that these assignments were assigned to, had changed to 20.

I thought this could be done using the following code:

```
AssignmentDetails['colname'] = AssignmentDetails.groupby(['ownerid','groupid','assignmentid']).cumcount()
```

But this doesn't give me the required result. It doesn't repeat the value in the new column when the values in the 'groupby' clause are the same, but it increments the values.

How do I achieve this? Any help would be great.

Comment: You have `OwnerID` of `1` and `GroupID` of `20` and three different `AssignementID`, namely `[100, 200, 300]`.  According to your logic, the results should be `[1, 2, 3]` but you have `[1, 1, 1]`.  Which is incorrect?  The results you've shown or the logic you've stated.

Comment: @piRSquared You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it now. My apologies for confusing you.

Comment: before you edited , That is confused me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.assign(
    result=df.groupby(
        ['OwnerID', 'GroupID']
    ).AssignmentID.transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]) + 1
)

   OwnerID  GroupID  AssignmentID  Result  result
0        1       10           100       1       1
1        1       10           100       1       1
2        1       10           200       2       2
3        1       20           100       1       1
4        1       20           200       1       2
5        1       20           300       1       3
6        2       30           200       1       1
7        2       30           200       1       1
8        2       40           300       2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
df.groupby([ 'OwnerID' , 'GroupID' ]).AssignmentID.transform(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1))
Out[186]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    3
6    1
7    1
8    1
Name: AssignmentID, dtype: int8
```

Comment: Nice one @Wen (-: